# C++/CLI: return a reference to unmanaged object

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I'm looking for a way to return the reference to another object that is a member of a managed object. This can be easily achieved in C++, but is a challenge for C++/CLI wrapper to be used with C#. Below is reproducible scenario (it's a lot of code, but it's all very easy, just demonstrating the problem)

C++ classes:

```
class NATIVEAPI NativeSlave
{
public:
    NativeSlave() : x_( 0 ), y_( 0.0 )
    {}

    NativeSlave( int x, double y ) : x_( x ), y_( y )
    {}

    int x_;
    double y_;
};

class NATIVEAPI NativeMaster
{
public:
    __declspec( property( get = getSlave, put = setSlave ) ) NativeSlave& slave;
    NativeSlave& getSlave()
    {
        return *pSlave; //returns a reference
    }
    void setSlave( const NativeSlave& slave )
    {
        *pSlave = slave;
    }

public:
    NativeMaster() : pSlave( new NativeSlave( 4, 5.0 ) )
    {}
    ~NativeMaster()
    {
        delete pSlave;
    }

private:
    NativeSlave* pSlave;
};
```

C++ usage:

```
NativeSlave slave = NativeSlave( 1, 2.0 ); //now, slave.x==1, slave.y==2.0
NativeMaster master; //now, master.slave.x==4, master.slave.y==5.0

master.slave = slave; //now, master.slave.x==1, master.slave.y==2.0
master.slave.x_ = 6; //now, master.slave.x==6
master.slave.y_ = 10.0; //now, master.slave.y==10.0
```

So in C++, we can easily get a reference to an underlying object and operate on its methods (here, members are public to simplify the example).

Then, the goal is to wrap this in C++/CLI to achieve the same functionality(usage) in C# as in C++ above:

C# **(desired)**:

```
ManagedSlave slave = new ManagedSlave(1, 2.0); //now, slave.x==1, slave.y==2.0
ManagedMaster master = new ManagedMaster(); //desired: master.slave.x==4, master.slave.y==5.0

master.slave = slave; //desired: master.slave.x==1, master.slave.y==2.0
master.slave.x = 6; //no appropriate get() method to change master.slave
master.slave.y = 10.0; //no appropriate get() method to change master.slave
```

Here is an attempt to write a wrapper:

C++/CLI (**with a problem in get/set property methods**):

```
public ref class ManagedSlave
{
public:
    property int x
    {
        int get()
        {
            return mSlave->x_;
        }
        void set( int x )
        {
            mSlave->x_ = x;
        }
    }
    property double y
    {
        double get()
        {
            return mSlave->y_;
        }
        void set( double y )
        {
            mSlave->y_ = y;
        }
    }
public:
    ManagedSlave( int x, double y ) : mSlave( new NativeSlave( x, y ) )
    {}
    ~ManagedSlave()
    {
        delete mSlave;
    }

internal:
    NativeSlave* mSlave;
};

public ref class ManagedMaster
{
public:
    property ManagedSlave^ slave
    {
        ManagedSlave^ get()
        {
            //??????????????????????????
        };
        void set( ManagedSlave^ slave )
        {
            //is this correct???????????
            mMaster->slave.x_ = slave->x;
            mMaster->slave.y_ = slave->y;
        };
    }

public:
    ManagedMaster() : mMaster( new NativeMaster() )
    {}
    ~ManagedMaster()
    {
        delete mMaster;
    }

internal:
    NativeMaster* mMaster;
};
```

Comment: Note that your native code uses unnecessary dynamic allocation and breaks the rule of three.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, you are right.. I omitted copy ctor and assignment operator for the sake of example length...

Comment: You are asking for C++/CLI to provide a C# usage model that no C# programmer has ever seen... probably not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET "references" are nothing like C++ references.

There is something in .NET that is the equivalent of a C++ reference, the `ref` keyword that qualifies arguments.  But there's no way to use it for anything except arguments.  (At the IL level it can be used for local variables also, but still not on return types)

Most of the time you can solve this by an extra layer of indirection.

In your particular case, it's really easy:

```
ManagedSlave( NativeSlave* s ) : mSlave( s )
{}
~ManagedSlave()
{
    // empty
}

ManagedSlave^ ManagedMaster::slave::get()
{
     return gcnew ManagedSlave( &mMaster->getSlave() );
}

// remove ManagedMaster::slave::set
```

Basically, there's no reason for `ManagedSlave` to be responsible for allocating and freeing a `NativeSlave`, because `NativeMaster` already does that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very new to ,NET, but trying to understand hard... You are saying that `ManagedSlave` doesn't need to free the pointer member? But then how the memory would be freed for this object: `ManagedSlave slave = new ManagedSlave(1, 2.0);` ?

Comment: If there is not `set` method, then `master.slave = slave;` fails since it's readonly, right?

Comment: @OlegShirokikh: In C++/CLI, it works fine and calls the copy-assignment operator of `ManagedSlave`, which can copy all the `NativeSlave` fields.  In C#, you could either use syntax like `master.slave.CopyFrom(otherSlave)` that reflects that the `slave` property is not actually being replaced by a new object, or you could use a setter that's more succinct but misleading.

Comment: @Oleg: `ManagedSlave slave = new ManagedSlave(1, 2.0);` wouldn't be possible.  The naming suggests to me that slave objects are not supposed to exist apart from their masters.  I suppose you could try to do both in a single class, but that gets messy.  Or use inheritance, so that `master.slave` returns a `NonOwningSlave^`, and `ManagedSlave` inherits from that and also performs allocation and deallocation.

Comment: @OlegShirokikh: If you want `master.slave = otherSlave;` to copy members, like a value type, not make both point to the same object instance, then `ManagedSlave` should be a value type.  In which case you would not wrap a `NativeSlave` object, but convert between them when necessary.  But that breaks `master.slave.x = 6;`