# C++/CLI: return a reference to unmanaged object in a C#.NET app

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am wrapping some functionality from a native C++ dll to .NET with C++/CLI. One of my native classes (class UA) has a method that returns a reference to another native class/object (class UB). I have wrapped both classes in my C++/CLI project as follows:

```cpp
//Unmanaged classes
class UA 
{
public:
A(int x) : m_x(x) {}
int m_x;
};

class UB 
{
public:
UB() : a(1) {}
UA& get_A(){return a;}
protected:
UA a;
};

// managed classes /CLI
public ref class A
{
internal:
A(UA* a) : m_ptr(a) {}
public:
A() : m_ptr(new UA(1)) {}
~A()
{
  this->!A();
}
!A()
{
  if (m_ptr != nullptr)
  {
     delete m_ptr;
  }
}
private:
UA* m_ptr;
};

public ref class B 
{
public:
B() : m_ptr(new UB()) {}
A^ get_A(){return gcnew A(&m_ptr->get_A())}
~B()
{
  this->!B();
}
!B()
{
  if (m_ptr != nullptr)
  {
     delete m_ptr;
  }
}
private:
UB* m_ptr;
};
```

The above compiles with `/clr`; however, when tested in a C#.NET app, I get a Debug Assertion Error.

```cs
// C#.NET app
B b = new B();
A = b.get_A();
```

This error occurs in the finalizer `(!A())` of the managed wrapping `class A`. In particular, it is raised when the GC is trying to delete the native pointer. I guess this happens simply why I have not created this instance with the new keyword. Do you think that it would be better to use a copy constructor in the native C++ and then create a managed wrapping class with the new keyword?

For example:

```cpp
//Unmanaged classes
class UA 
{
public:
A(int x) : m_x(x) {}
A(const A& a)
{
  m_x = a.m_x;
}
int m_x;
};
```

And then the managed A and B wrappers will be:

```cpp
// managed classes /CLI
public ref class A
{
internal:
A(UA* a) : m_ptr(a) {}
public:
A() : m_ptr(new UA(1)) {}
~A()
{
  this->!A();
}
!A()
{
  if (m_ptr != nullptr)
  {
     delete m_ptr;
  }
}
private:
UA* m_ptr;
};

public ref class B 
{
public:
B() : m_ptr(new B()) {}
A^ get_A(){return gcnew A(new UA(&m_ptr->get_A()))}
~B()
{
  this->!B();
}
!B()
{
  if (m_ptr != nullptr)
  {
     delete m_ptr;
  }
}
private:
UB* m_ptr;
};
```

Is there any different approach to return a reference to an unmanaged object in C#? Apologies if I do something fundamentally wrong, I have very small experience in C++/CLI. I also have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025046/c-cli-return-a-reference-to-unmanaged-object); however, it seems that the accepted answer proposes the solution I firstly implemented.
I appreciate any help/suggestion.

Comment: Interesting to see your C# code too. The code that produces the assertion.

Comment: Hi @vahancho, see the edit above.

Comment: The code is nonsense and cannot compile, makes it hard to help you.  All that I can really see is that the destructors are not safe and will trigger this diagnostic when the C# code disposes the object more than once.  Easy to fix by setting the pointer to nullptr.  Whether that's the real cause of the heap corruption is impossible to guess, C++ code rarely needs a lot of help to bomb like this.

Comment: @GiorgosR, the problem is probably in this line: `A^ get_A(){return gcnew A(&m_ptr->get_A())}`. Pointer in `A` object refers to the object in another object. When you destroy `A` it tries to delete an object which was already deleted.

Comment: Hi Hans, many thanks for the reply. The c++ is just an example. I tried to simplify/convert my real code to an example. The issue here is how I could return a native reference in a C# wrapper class. The only possibility I see is with a copy constructor either in c++/cli or in C++.

Comment: I think, @Hans Passant suggestion to set my pointer to null in `(!(A) finalizer)` is correct when I instantiate an object with the `A(UA*)` constructor. However, I can't understand how I will delete the pointer when I ll use the `A()` constructor.

Comment: That's not obvious either, what is the C# code going to do with an unmanaged object reference?  The entire point of writing a C++/CLI wrapper is that *all* operations on that pointer are wrapped with easy-to-use managed methods.

Comment: I see, that's why I said that copying the object from c++ to c# is maybe better than holding a reference to a native object. However, I saw some other answers here with the way I firstly implemented. Thus, I thought that it is not bad practice to return a reference to an unmanaged object and wrap it in a managed class.

Answer (score 0):

This is just due to the fact that when you call `b.get_A()`, this calls your internal constructor `A(UA* a) : m_ptr(a) {}` which just stores the pointer to field `a` of an object of type `UB`. The destructor will then try to delete this pointer which cannot work.

This has nothing to do with C++/CLI, just be symmetric with allocations and deletions. In this case just remove your public constructor `A()` which does an allocation and also those destructors and it will work.

Comment: Hi @Peebo, thanks for your help. I can't remove the constructor `A()` because there are times that I need to create a new object `A` from my c# app.

Comment: @GiorgosR it's not the constructor, it's what it does. You're allocating some memory in one case, that you are correctly deleting at the end, but in the other case you're just copying a pointer that you can't just delete. If this is really what you need, you may initialise a separate boolean field depending on which constructor was called and use this information in the destructor. Not sure if this is good design though